# Using killall with -u and -o options

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, htop

I wanted to confirm some details with the killall -o option. I tested it on some ssh connections I created under the user rick. 
First I printed a list of all of ricks ssh connections along with the etime. `ps -u rick -o user,pid,etime --sort=etime`

Next, I ran the following:
`killall -i -o 9h ssh-agent`. I went and checked each PID against my killall interactive list. The -o option appears to use the elapsed time. However, I want to be able to ensure my killall statement only includes ssh-agents from rick.

I tried `killall -i -u rick -o 9h` but it kills all rick ssh-agents regardless of the etime.

Comment: If you're on OSX, you might want to check your local man page (`man killall`) to see if the `-o` option is supported. The man page I found [here](https://ss64.com/osx/killall.html) does not list that option. I'm guessing on the OSX part because I saw another question on your profile that's about using `find` on OSX :-).

Comment: I'm on Linux. Here is the link of the mange page I am using 
http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/killall.1.html

Comment: Ah, okay. While the man page at the given link looks okay, you should still prefer your local man page whenever possible. The local man page usually comes from the same package as the binaries, so it should be the most accurate representation of what your local copy of `killall` can do.

Comment: Totally understand. It seems that I just need to get the options in the correct order maybe? I know killall -i -o 9h ssh-agent works and uses the elapsed time but how would I go about changing this to check for a user instead?